# PHP class doesn't recognize this->method()

Tags: php

When trying to access a method I've defined in a PHP class from within another method in the same class, I get the following error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in /var/www/`...`/TOC.php on line 57`

Previously, I'd these functions sitting outside of any class, just including them where I needed them.  Having moved them into one, at first I thought I must be having the issue [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885245/php-does-not-recognize-method-defined-in-class) was having, but with an instance of the class, I can call my render method from another file with no problems.  Commenting out the line `this->printTreeArray($sectionProjects);` eliminates the error.  Here's my class:

```
<?php

class TOC{

    private function printTreeArray($sectionProjects){
        echo "var TOCnodes = [\n";

        //Print each section, with another loop to print each one's problems
        $i = 0;
        foreach($sectionProjects as $sectionProject){
            if($i != 0){
                echo ",\n";
            }

            $project = $sectionProject->getProject();
            //Get due date for mouseover text
            $due = $project->getDueDate('F jS, Y h:i A');

            $q = new ProjectProblemQuery();
            $projectProblems = $q->findByRelProjectId($project->getId());

            $pId = $i + 1;
            echo "{id: $pId, pId: 0, name: \"Project $pId\", title: \"Due: $due\", isParent: true, open: true}";

            //Print this section's problem list
            $probId = 1;
            foreach($projectProblems as $projectProblem){
                echo ",\n";

                $nodeId = ($pId * 10) + $j;

                echo "{id: $nodeId, pId: $pId, name: \"$pId.$probId\", url: \"#\", target: \"_top\"}";

                $j++;
            }

            $i++;
        }
        echo"];\n";
    }

    public function render($section){
        if(! $section instanceof Section){
            echo "$section is not an instance of Section!";
        }
        else{
            echo "<ul id=\"TOCtree\" class=\"ztree\"></ul>\n";

            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";

            $sectionProjects = $section->getSectionProjects();

            this->printTreeArray($sectionProjects);

            echo "$(document).ready(function () {
                    $.fn.zTree.init($(\"#TOCtree\"), setting, TOCnodes);
                });";
            echo "</script>";
        }
    }


}
```

This is my first time asking a question on SO - generally I've been able to find answers to my coding dilemmas, but this one has me baffled.  I realize there's a lot of not-elegant stuff going on in this class, so if there's a point of style I can use to avoid this sort of error in the future, I'd greatly appreciate getting to learn it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$this` instead of `this`.

Comment: D'oh! Good to know $this is a variable in a class.  Coming out of Java, I figured it was a keyword or something.  Thanks!